# Meteor throws an error in promise_server.js?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, proxy, localhost

I am new to Meteor and first had some problems with babel function name ...
but now it throws an exepction in promise_server.js   Type Error

localhost 3000 is blocked in chrome: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

changing meteor version doesnt help. Hope you can help me :D

Version: Meteor 1.3.3.1

Win 10

```
=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
=> Babel active on file extensions: es6.js, es6, jsx

C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.3_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:165
  throw error;
        ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'displayName' of undefined
at SourceProcessorSet.addLegacyHandler (C:\tools\isobuild\build-plugin.js:142:64)
at C:\tools\isobuild\build-plugin.js:172:12
at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.3_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:87:22)
at SourceProcessorSet.merge (C:\tools\isobuild\build-plugin.js:170:7)
at C:\tools\isobuild\compiler.js:376:26
at Array.forEach (native)
at C:\tools\isobuild\compiler.js:372:26
at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:359:18
at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:352:34
at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:350:23
at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
at Object.enterJob (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:324:26)
at C:\tools\isobuild\compiler.js:368:16
at C:\tools\isobuild\compiler.js:176:26
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.3_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
at Object.compile (C:\tools\isobuild\compiler.js:171:5)
at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2571:24
at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:271:13
at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:264:29
at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:262:18
at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:253:23
at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
at Object.capture (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:252:19)
at Object.exports.bundle (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2514:31)
at C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:591:36
at Function.run (C:\tools\tool-env\profile.js:489:12)
at bundleApp (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:581:34)
at AppRunner._runOnce (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:634:35)
at AppRunner._fiber (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:887:28)
at C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:411:12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection refused message means that the server is unreachable. This is correct since the server has crashed due to an incorrect function call: Cannot call method 'displayName' of undefined.

Maybe similar to this issue? https://github.com/flemay/less-autoprefixer/issues/4

In the referenced issue it is resolved by removing the "less" package

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue arise when you are running meteor to an android device.  In my  case the problem was caused due the app was installed in the device and it had been installed using Google Play, so maybe meteor could't overwrite it.

> The problem was solved uninstalling the app previously installed via
>   Google Play.